# Symfony Webpack - using custom fonts from subdirectory

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, fonts, sass

I have problem with compiling sass files with custom made font files.

This is how my directory structure looks like:

### app.scss file content:

`@import '../../../libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/css/helper';`

### helper.scss file content:

```
@import "helpers/grid";
@import "helpers/colors";
@import "helpers/fonts";
```

### fonts.scss file content:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "custom-font";
    src: url("../../fonts/custom-font.eot");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

### Custom Bundles files location:

`/var/www/libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/font/custom-font.eot`

`/var/www/libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/css/helper.scss`

`/var/www/libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/css/helpers/fonts.scss`

What url should I provide? I have tried `../../../../libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/fonts/custom-font.eot` (relative to website build directory), `../../fonts/custom-font.eot` (relative to library scss file).

But I am still getting this error while running `yarn run encore dev` command:

> This relative module was not found:
>
> * ../../../../libraries/SymfonyBundle/assets/font/custom-font.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--4-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-3!./assets/css/app.scss`

### webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous 
directory
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {}, {
             resolveUrlLoader: false
    })

   // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a global 
variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run Encore, a manifest.json file is automatically created in your outputPath directory. Check your paths in this file. Especially the slashes: and the value of the setOutputPath: ./build/ vs /buld vs build.

Can be tricky if your Symfony lives in a subdir (like http://dev.local/my-symfony-app/) too. See: this paragraph in [Symfony official FAQ](http://symfony.com/doc/master/frontend/encore/faq.html#my-app-lives-under-a-subdirectory)